# Flutter Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter project where I'm already making use of Firebase & Firestore for database. While setting up those services, there was a file called `google-services.json` that had to be downloaded and stored in the project directory.

Comment: Are you sure it's a new service.json or is it an accessKey.json?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to overwrite the `google-service.json` since it use the same firebase project.

Answer (score 0):

The file you get from setting up FCM is a service account key which should be used for your backend which can be Firebase Functions basically this is used with firebase admin